# Cannot connect to HTTPS sites due to device clock being ahead

Tags: browser, clock, https

I cannot access 'My Search.com' I just set as my homepage (Brave browser) and Yandex for my search engine (new install). I got an error saying that my (device) time is ahead.

> [image] [image]
>
> #### Your clock is ahead
>
> A private connection to *example.com** can't be established because your device's date and time (`[current date and time]`) are incorrect.
>
> NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
>
> To establish a secure connection, your clock needs to be set correctly. This is because the certificates that websites use to identify themselves are only valid for specific periods of time. Since your device's clock is incorrect, Chromium cannot verify these certificates.

I have checked that the time and timezone is correct. Also, daylight savings time occured since yesterday.

How to fix the issue?

Comment: I believe there might be some sort of auto-sync for date-time in your device. Did you check that?

Comment: What model phone and what carrier? Carriers often have a number you can dial that initiates phone reprogramming, which should do things such as fixing time zone issues.

Comment: Which country and time zone are you in? A daylight savings time starting on 10th March is very early, may be your phone does not correctly considers that and therefore you are 1 hour in the future.